# Make each column a sum of all previous columns for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
           2019 Jan  2019 Mar  2019 Apr  2019 May  2019 Jun
 CASC\n         2.0       2.0       2.0       1.0       2.0
 SpaceX\n       1.0       1.0       1.0       2.0       2.0
```

which you can get using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {
    '2019 Jan': {' CASC\n': 2.0, ' SpaceX\n': 1.0},
    '2019 Mar': {' CASC\n': 2.0, ' SpaceX\n': 1.0},
    '2019 Apr': {' CASC\n': 2.0, ' SpaceX\n': 1.0},
    '2019 May': {' CASC\n': 1.0, ' SpaceX\n': 2.0},
    '2019 Jun': {' CASC\n': 2.0, ' SpaceX\n': 2.0}
 }

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

I wanted to make each column to be a sum of all the previous columns, so the final dataframe would be like this:

```
           2019 Jan  2019 Mar  2019 Apr  2019 May  2019 Jun
 CASC\n         2.0       4.0       6.0       7.0       9.0
 SpaceX\n       1.0       2.0       3.0       5.0       7.0
```

I could get a sum of all the columns and make it a new column with this code:

```
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:,:].sum(axis=1)
```

which would result in the following dataframe:

```
           2019 Jan  2019 Mar  2019 Apr  2019 May  2019 Jun  Total
 CASC\n         2.0       2.0       2.0       1.0       2.0    9.0
 SpaceX\n       1.0       1.0       1.0       2.0       2.0    7.0
```

but it is obviously not what I want. Instead I want each column act as "Total" for the previous columns and itself. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df=df.cumsum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           2019 Jan  2019 Mar  2019 Apr  2019 May  2019 Jun
 CASC\n         2.0       4.0       6.0       7.0       9.0
 SpaceX\n       1.0       2.0       3.0       5.0       7.0
```